# Backbone collections unique identifier / syncing MongoDB collections using socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, backbone.js

I am using MongoDB with Node.js on the backend and Backone on the front-end. Backbone models have unique ids (cid's and idAttribute) that can identify the models on the backend. But Backbone collections do *not* have a unique identifier to my knowledge, and that is one reason why I ask the question that emerges from the remainder of the text below:

In MongoDB, collections have names as strings, which represent their unique identifier. What is the best way to match the collection string name in MongoDB with some sort of unique string name for a Backbone collection on the front-end?

Do Backbone collections have some sort of unique identifier? What is the best way to create one?

The reason why I ask is because normally we match Backbone collections with the backend using the URL property of the collection. However, I am starting to incorporate sockets (socket.io) in my application. It goes like this: I have a secondary server (separate from the application server) that listens to the MongoDB [oplog](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/). Upon an insert/update/delete event in the oplog, the secondary server sends a socket message to my front-end with BSON/JSON information that contains: `<dbname>.<collectionname>`. So something like: `mainDB.users_collection`

So on my front-end, I need to match the Backbone collection with the literal string representation of the MongoDB collection. Now, I could just set a property on the Backbone collection, say, "uniqueName" but I am wondering if there is a better practice. Someone has done this before and I want to learn from them. Good grief.

Comment: Wouldn't you just have one `Backbone.Collection` for each MongoDB collection? And trying to use a `cid` to identify models server-side isn't going to work very well so don't even think about it.

Comment: I am not using cid's for anything, just using MondoDB _id's. But the issue remains. yes more or less, 1:1 ratio between front-end Backbone collections and MongoDB collections.

Comment: So what's wrong with using names for your Backbone collections? `whatever = Backbone.Collection.extend({ ... })` and such?

Comment: I think you see my point that models have cid's/id's but collections don't. I am just look for best practice as to how to create unique identifiers for collections?

Comment: Names. Backbone collections, MongoDB collections, RDBMS tables, ... have names. That's all there is to it.

Comment: Most Backbone collections I've ever used simply have variables - the names of those are their unique id. Are you trying to have a collection of collections or something like that where a variable name is insufficient? If so, you might be able to define a model type which holds a collection which would have an id with the proper name.

Comment: This sounds a bit like an XY-problem, meaning you have problem X and you think you have to solve it by doing Y so you ask about Y. Can you clarify the **reason** why you think you need unique identifiers for your collections?

Comment: hey Mu and Ivarni, I added an explanation. Although I believe it is necessary to explain the reason for what I want to do so that other people get it, it pains me to have to explain myself.

Comment: It matters because if you weren't using sockets I would suggest doing exactly what you did before introducing them, namely use the URL property. The fact that you **are** using sockets is very relevant. Now that we know what you're trying to do we could suggest a solution using Backbone.Sync. You probably want to do something like [this](https://noveogroup.github.io/backbone.iobind/).

Comment: ivarni, thanks, would you mind distilling that to a short answer to original question for others?

Comment: sorry @DarthDerr i missed your comment yesterday. i added some info which you probably saw already, but hopefully that clarifies if you were at all curious as to why I was asking the question in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way of integrating Backbone with sockets is to change the `Backbone.Sync` object. The default [Sync](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) assumes a traditional REST API and is meant to be changed when a different backend is used.

Alternatively, you can use an existing plugin, like https://noveogroup.github.io/backbone.iobind/

Comment: as of now, I just kept Backbone's standard HTTP REST configuration and wrote my own functionality to handle real-time socket updates. In other words, I only listen for updates with socket.io, I don't don't save anything from the client to the server with socket.io. seems to be the simplest way to do it, and probably covers 80% of use cases if you aren't doing chat. socket.io connections seem to get dropped all the time so I question the reliability of saving data to server with socket.io instead of HTTP...